# Adding several columns in update query

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-update

Im trying to update several columns in a row through a dynamic query.

columnnames is an Arraylist containing all the names of the columns for the selected table

Arrays.toString(row) contains the user inputs that the row should be updated to.

Im getting this error message at columnnames when trying to run this: No such column[SNO,SNAME,STATUS,CITY]. I dont know of any way to fix this?

```
 query = "UPDATE " + tablename + " SET '" + columnnames  + "' = '" + Arrays.toString(row) + "' WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + rowstandard + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update each column separately.  You can't pass them each as arrays.

```
 query = "UPDATE " + tablename + " SET "
 foreach(int i=0; i< columnnames.length; i++)
 {
     query+= "'" + columnnames[i]  + "' = '" + row[i] + "',"
 }
 query = StripLastComma(query) //Not sure how to do this in Java.
 query +="' WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + rowstandard + "'"
```

Comment: looks great i just don't know how to strip that last comma? :/

Comment: In C# it would be query = query.Substring(0,query.length-1).  Something like that in Java as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not going to work as the syntax for set is SET ColumnA = :ValueA, ColumnB = :ValueB WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + rowstandard + "'";

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out correct syntax for update query is:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

see [Update syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Having said that, I would do something like this (using [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)):

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("UPDATE " + tablename + " SET ");
// build a map of col name/value
Map<String, String> map = Maps.toMap(columnnames, new Function<String, String>(){
        @Override
        public String apply(String input){
            return row[columnnames.indexOf(input)].toString();
        }
    });
query.append(Joiner.on(",").withKeyValueSeparator("=").join(map));
query.append(" WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + rowstandard + "'");
query.toString();
```

Comment: Well i see bill gregs solution as the best to my program though do you know of how i can get rid of that last comma? since i tried printing it out and the only thing ruining my query is that last comma

Comment: in mine - there is no such issue ;) but if you want to get rid of last comma you can do something like this: `query = query.substring(0, query.lastIndexOf(","));` you need to add it instead of `query = StripLastComma(query)'